# Incorrect result using custom listview adapter and different layouts

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Hello Stack Overflow Android Users,

Please help with the following question:
I`m trying to create a listview, where in some cases background color of some row changes for different one.
Here is some code. 
This is MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> values;  
    String[] names = {"Astor", "Brian", "Cody", "Dexter", "Emma", "Finch", "Glenn"};
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        values = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for(int i = 0; i<6; i++){
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", ""+i);
            map.put("title", names[i]);
            values.add(map);            
        }       
        final mAdapter adapter = new mAdapter(this, R.layout.list1, values);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
          });   
    }
```

And this is my custom adapter class mAdapter.class:

```
public class mAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> values;
    public mAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Map<String, String>> values){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
        this.values = values;
    }
    public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup p){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(v == null){              
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list1, null);             
        }
        TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        t.setText("Position: " + pos);              
        if(pos == 2){               
            v.setBackgroundColor(0x30ff0000);
            t.setText("!!!Position: " + pos);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

When I run this application I get such result:
The default background color is grey. As you see, color was changed not only for row with "pos" 2, but also for rows with "pos" 0 and 5. But on the other hand, text was changed only for the right row with "pos" equals 2. 
Can anyone explain why this happens and what is the way to solve this?

Thank you

P.S. Seems, I have not enough points to post images. This is screenshot of result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bHeC.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the default color as grey in the else case as well

Something like this

```
if(pos == 2){               
        v.setBackgroundColor(0x30ff0000);
        t.setText("!!!Position: " + pos);
    }
else {
    v.setBackgroundColor(color code for grey);
}
```

This is happening because you are reusing the convert view